# Statistics::R @INC don't locate

Tags: r, macos, perl

I am a newbie on Perl and I have a problem with the module Statitics::R.

I have to install a software (Sowhat:https://github.com/josephryan/sowhat) on a mac. For this I need Statistics::R. I downloaded it and put the compressed directory on my sowhat directory. After this I decompressed my directory and install my Module. I tried to install my software and then I obtained this answer

Error:

> Can't locate Statistics/R.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Statistics::R module) (@INC contains:
>   /Users/UMR7205/Documents/sowhat-master/blib/lib
>   /Users/UMR7205/Documents/sowhat-master/blib/arch
>   /Users/UMR7205/Documents/sowhat-master/blib/lib/Statistics-R0.34/lib/Statistics/R.pm
>   /Users/UMR7205/Documents/sowhat-master/blib/lib/Statistics-R0.34/lib/Statistics/R.pm
>   /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.18
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at (eval 4) line 2.  BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.

But:

- The directory which contains the Statistics/R.pm" is listed here
- When I checked the installation of Statistics::R I have the same answer
- I had no error message when I install the package

Could someone help me?

Comment: What are you doing? How did the ***file*** `/Users/UMR7205/Documents/sowhat-master/blib/lib/Statistics-R0.34/lib/Statistics/R.pm` get in to your `@INC`? That file is from your *build* directory. I am guessing you built the module using `make`, but did not do `make install` and instead thought you should put the file path in `@INC`. First, don't mess with the `perl` environment that comes with your OS. Compile your own `perl`. Second, after that install the module using one of the convenient utilities so all the dependencies also get installed.

Comment: Also, FYI, if you have a module `My::Module` in `/some/path/here/or/there/My/Module.pm`, you need `/some/path/here/or/there` in your `@INC` for `perl` to find it, but you rarely have to do this ***if*** you avoid just throwing everything at a wall and see what sticks. Read [perldoc -f require](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#require-EXPR) for how `perl` looks for modules.

Answer (score -1):

if you have R installed it is enough to say `sudo  perl -MCPAN -e 'install Statistics::R'` in terminal to install this package where it  should be

Comment: [Don't mess with the system `perl`](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/11/apple-recommends-installing-your-own-perl/).

Answer (score -1):

I belive you may need some configuration first.
Please try to follow the step in this guide.

From http://triopter.com/archive/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-4-easy-steps/

1) Make sure you have the Apple Developer Tools (XCode) installed.

2) Configure CPAN.
`$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell`
`perl> o conf init`

> This will prompt you for some settings. You can accept the defaults
>   for almost everything (just hit “return”). The two things you must
>   fill in are the path to make (which should be /usr/bin/make or the
>   value returned when you run which make from the command line) and your
>   choice of CPAN mirrors (which you actually choose don’t really matter,
>   but it won’t let you finish until you select at least one). If you use
>   a proxy or a very restrictive firewall, you may have to configure
>   those settings as well. If you skip Step 2, you may get errors about
>   make being unavailable.

3) Upgrade CPAN
`$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::CPAN'`

4) Install your modules. For each module….
`$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::Name'`
or
`$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Module::Name'`

Comment: [Don't mess with the system `perl`](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/11/apple-recommends-installing-your-own-perl/).